# Get startup type of Windows service using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

How can I get the Windows service startup type using PowerShell and not using [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)?

I looked inside the [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-5.1) command, and it does not provide something to display the "startup type".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With PowerShell version 4:

You can run a command as given below:

```
   Get-Service | select -property name,starttype
```

Comment: This seems to work on v5 only - tested on v4 and v2 and the StartType field doesn't populate

Comment: This doesn't work either in v5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2. It does work on Windows 10, both locally and querying a remote Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Reminder to self: adding `| Select-Object *` will list **all** properties on Windows 10 with PowerShell `PSVersion=5.1.17134.407`

Comment: The property was added to the underlying class in .NET 4.6.1 -- the version of PowerShell is irrelevant  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.starttype

Answer (score 42):

WMI is the way to do this.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select StartMode From Win32_Service Where Name='winmgmt'"
```

Or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Property StartMode -Filter "Name='Winmgmt'"
```

Comment: is there a way to change the starttype via PowerShell ?

Comment: Sure. `$svc = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Winmgmt'"; $svc.StartMode='Manual'; $svc.psbase.put()

Comment: how do i see if delayed start is set for service?

Comment: The only way I know is to use the Registry Key: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx

Answer (score 15):

In PowerShell you can use the command [Set-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Set-Service -Name Winmgmt -StartupType Manual
```

I haven't found a PowerShell command to view the startup type though. One would assume that the command Get-Service would provide that, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Maybe useful: Set-Service -Name Winmgmt -StartupType Manual -Status running - view http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_service_set.htm

Answer (score 12):

You can use also:

```
(Get-Service 'winmgmt').StartType
```

It returns just the startup type, for example, *disabled*.

Comment: This appears to only work on PS v5. I tested on v2 and v4 but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know there is no “native” PowerShell way of getting this information. And perhaps it is rather the .NET limitation than PowerShell.

Here is the suggestion to add this functionality to the version next:

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/424948/i-would-like-to-see-the-property-starttype-added-to-get-services

The WMI workaround is also there, just in case. I use this WMI solution for my tasks and it works.

Comment: Status as of 2015-10-10: [*This is fixed and will be available in the next Technical Preview of Windows Server 2016.*](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/424948/i-would-like-to-see-the-property-starttype-added-to-get-services)

Answer (score 5):

Once you've [upgraded to PowerShell version 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) you can get the startup type.

To check the version of PowerShell you're running, use `$PSVersionTable`.

The examples below are for the Windows Firewall Service:

**For the local system**

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,StartType | where-object {$_.Name -eq "MpsSvc"} | Format-Table -auto
```

**For one remote system**

```
Get-Service -ComputerName HOSTNAME_OF_SYSTEM | Select-Object -Property MachineName,Name,Status,StartType | where-object {$_.Name -eq "MpsSvc"} | Format-Table -auto
```

**For multiple systems (must create the systems.txt)**

```
Get-Service -ComputerName (Get-content c:\systems.txt) | Select-Object -Property MachineName,Name,Status,StartType | where-object {$_.Name -eq "MpsSvc"} | Format-Table -auto
```

Comment: It's also possible to do this without piping: `(Get-Service -Name MpsSvc).StartType`

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Get-Service BITS | Select StartType
```

Or use:

```
(Get-Service -Name BITS).StartType
```

***Then***

```
Set-Service BITS -StartupType xxx
```

[PowerShell 5.1]

Answer (score 2):

If you update to PowerShell 5 you can query all of the services on the machine and display Name and StartType and sort it by StartType for easy viewing:

```
Get-Service |Select-Object -Property Name,StartType |Sort-Object -Property StartType
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`sc`](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) tool to set it.

You can also call it from PowerShell and add additional checks if needed.
The advantage of this tool vs. PowerShell is that the `sc` tool can also set the start type to auto delayed.

```
# Get Service status
$Service = "Wecsvc"
sc.exe qc $Service

# Set Service status
$Service = "Wecsvc"
sc.exe config $Service start= delayed-auto
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with PowerShell 4.

```
Get-Service *spool* | select name,starttype | ft -AutoSize
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJnZN.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default **StartType** is not shown by `Get-Service`, but you can always explicitly ask for it:

```
Get-Service | select StartType,DisplayName | sort StartType,DisplayName
```

Use `Get-Service | Get-Member` to see all available fields.