# Cannot get service StartType in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that scans a list of servers/computers for a service and displays the status.

I am running PS version 5 Build 10586 Revision 117 on both of my computers.

On my Windows 7 computer running PSv5, the StartType is outputted to the .txt

```
MachineName  ServiceName                 Status StartType
-----------  -----------                 ------ ---------
srvcomp0201 My.ServiceName.Here          Stopped Stopped         
srvcomp0202 My.OtherServiceName          Running Running
```

When I run this same script on my Windows 2012 computer with PSv4 or v5, the StartType is not outputted to the .txt or .csv

```
MachineName  ServiceName                 Status StartType
-----------  -----------                 ------ ---------
srvcomp0201 My.ServiceName.Here          Stopped          
srvcomp0202 My.OtherServiceName          Running
```

I can change the order that is supposed to be displayed like:

```
$s | select MachineName, StartType, ServiceName, Status
```

And it still doesn't show anything when run on the Win2012 computer.

Why is it doing this?

```
$serviceList = Get-Content C:\services.txt

$results = Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {

    foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
        if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            $s | select MachineName, StartType, ServiceName, Status | Out-File C:\test.txt -Append
        } else {
            "$_ - Service '$service' does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This doesn't write the StartType to the file either:

```
$serviceList = Get-Content C:\services.txt

$results = Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {

    foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
        if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            $s | select MachineName, StartType | Out-File C:\test.txt -Append
        } else {
            "$_ - Service '$service' does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't display the StartType on my 2012 computer either:

```
get-content c:\servicelist\computers.txt | % {
    if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name W3SVC* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)  # change -name * to name of service
    {
        $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, StartType, Status
    }
    else {"Service is not available on $_"}
    }
```

Is this a Windows 2012 thing?

Comment: Have you tried piping to `Format-List` or `Get-Member` to see what properties are available? Perhaps `StartType` is there, simply under another name. Try `$s|fl *` and see what properties you have available on the 2012 machine.

Comment: fl * shows that it's not available.  I guess it has to do with Win2012.

Comment: @KadeWilliams I can't remember the details of _why_ that is, but you can use [Get-WmiObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306059/5039142) and `StartMode` of the results to work around it.

Comment: Fun fact: When you run `Get-Service` locally on a W2K12 server the property StartType does not seem to exist. When you run `Get-Service` remote against the same server the property StartType does exist in fact.

Comment: What is the Powershell version? [$PSVersionTable]. It needs to be v5+

Comment: I tried 5 and 5.1

Answer (score 2):

**Windows PowerShell has a range of cmdlets that do *not* use *PowerShell* remoting** (based on [[MS-PRSP], the PowerShell Remoting Protocol specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357801.aspx)), **typically identifiable by having their own `-ComputerName` parameter** (as opposed to invoking them via "meta"-invocation cmdlets such as `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`).

**Use of this obsolescent, DCOM-based, *per-cmdlet* remoting should be abandoned in favor of the *part-of-the-plumbing* PowerShell remoting**.
In fact, the per-cmdlet form of remoting is no longer available in PowerShell *Core*.

Therefore, instead of:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -name $service
```

use:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ { Get-Service $service }
```

The latter uses PowerShell remoting, whose requirements differ from the DCOM-based form remoting and may therefore require additional setup; see [`Get-Help about_Remoting_FAQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)

I cannot personally verify this, but based on [Olaf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) comment on the question, **this may *implicitly* solve your problem (for which I have no explanation)**.

Answer (score 1):

The default PowerShell version delivered with the OS would make a difference. [see https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/#powershell-and-windows-versions]
Windows 2012 comes with v3, but Windows 10 comes with v5, where StartType property is added.

Comment: I installed 5.0 and 5.1 but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you enforced it to use version 5? If not, can you check $host.Version?

Comment: I'm not sure how to enforce it.  When I run $host.Version I get Major: 5 Minor: 1 Build: 14409 Revision: 1005